# How does Skype hash the phone number to a fixed length?

Tags: encryption, hash, universal-hash

I have a Skype account with a phone number and I noticed that my contacts and I
who created the accounts with a phone number have the Skype ID 
in some form of a hash. But all the Skype IDs have the same length (16).
and the link prove skype hash the phone number
is here[how skype generate user id](http://www.skaip.org/the-developers-have-abolished-username-when-registering-on-skype)

What hash algorithm does Skype use for this?

Comment: Are you sure there's a hash involved?  I don't know about Skype, but usually a user id would be an auto-incrementing field in a database.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how a specific piece of software works rather than being about cryptography itself. It would be a better fit for a site like [superuser](superuser.com)

Comment: i think about that but no user id will increment but not to those numbers those are huge numbers and i read article said skype use hash for generate id and this is make sense and once i have problem in my account and ask the agent and he said i'm right they use hash do you think hex decimal number with length 16 will be user_id in the data base no

Comment: ella rose i don't think this question must be close but thank you any way fro suggest super user site to me i don't know it and may be i ask in it also

Comment: Can you post a reference to the article that says they use a hash?  The auto-increment field was more of an example, I don't suppose that's the exact method that Skype uses, it's too predictable and leaks information.  But I do suppose that it's closer to the truth than a hash is.

Comment: Also seconding Ella Rose's comment that "how does Skype assign account ids" is a Skype question and not a cryptography question.  If you are more interested in the hypothetical way that a system could use a hash to do this, that not the same question and I think could be within the scope of this site.

Comment: @bmm6o this is the link (http://www.skaip.org/the-developers-have-abolished-username-when-registering-on-skype)

Comment: @bmm6o look above i put the link also in the question

Comment: @EllaRose look above i put link to prove my thought on the question i thought about that for long time and thank you for suggest super user if you have any suggestions i hope you will tell me